# Nucleophilic Substitution Reaction of Alcohol

Tags: organic-chemistry, alcohols, nucleophilic-substitution

[image]

What is the final product?

According to me, it's option (3). But given answer in the booklet is (2).

Given primary alcohol undergoes SN2 reaction to produce isopentyl bromide and the latter again undergoes SN2 to form isopentyl cyanide.

Can someone please help?

Comment: Carbocations will rearrange to place the positive charge on more substituted carbon atoms.

Comment: @ringo Carbocation formation doesn't occur in SN2 mechanism.

Comment: The alcohol/HBr reaction is not SN2.

Comment: It absolutely does for primary or methyl alcohols.